# String#delete ignore special characters

Tags: ruby

`String#delete` interprets `a-z` as character range. However, I would like it to delete `fa-zo`.

```
"fojwfa-zowj".delete("fa-zo") #=> "-"
```

Desired result:

```
"fojwwj"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"fojwfa-zowj".gsub("fa-zo","")  # => "fojwwj"
```

Comment: And for `gsub` haters, do you have some other option?

Comment: yes, but complicated, maybe some regex with `#[]` can do this. The problem of `delete` is not only to escape the hyphen.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use this little trick:

```
string = "fojwfa-zowj"

string[/fa-zo/] = ''

string
# => "fojwwj"
```

Notice however, that this modifies the string in place like `#gsub!`, which should be faster and should use less memory, but which could introduce side-effects if not considered well.

Answer (score 2):

```
"fojwfa-zowj".tap{ |s| s.slice! "fa-zo" } # just for the Heaven of it
```